# How to set header in Azure Data Factory web activity by azure SDK for .net

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am just wondering how can i add header to the azure data factory web activity. I tried code below:

```
                new WebActivity()
                {
                    Name = "Authenticating",
                    Url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    Method = "POST",
                    Headers =  " \"Content-Type\": \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\""
                },
```

However, the code will result in

`"headers": {
            "0": " ",
            "1": "\"",
            "2": "C",
            "3": "o",
            "4": "n",
            "5": "t",
            "6": "e",
            "7": "n",
            "8": "t",
            "9": "-",
            "10": "T",
            "11": "y",
            "12": "p",
            "13": "e",
            "51": "\"",
            "seed": 1840253349
        },`

I went to their source code, they said

```
/// Gets or sets represents the headers that will be sent to the
/// request. For example, to set the language and type on a request:
/// "headers" : { "Accept-Language": "en-us", "Content-Type":
/// "application/json" }. Type: string (or Expression with resultType
/// string).
```

I also tried with {} within the string, like:

```
Headers =  " { \"Accept-Language\": \"en-us\", \"Content-Type\":\r\n/// \"application/json\" }",
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should pass in a Json object instead of string. Just changed the code to below and it worked.

```
Headers =JObject.Parse(@"{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}")
```